# get_release Oracle API returning "Unknown" result instead of correct release

Tags: oracle, erp, oracle-ebs

While executing below get_release function from apps user it’s returning the correct release: **12.1.3** , but when execute it from another user it’s returning **Unknown** result:

```
declare
l_release_name         varchar2(30);
l_other_release_info   varchar2(2000);
   begin
     if not apps.FND_RELEASE.get_release (l_release_name, l_other_release_info) then
         null;
     end if;
     dbms_output.put_line(l_release_name);
   end;
```

***FND_RELEASE.get_release***
 is a public package there should be no restriction on calling it from another user.

Below what I found in the function comments:

```
-- get_release() will usually return TRUE
  --  with RELEASE_NAME =
  --                    contents of RELEASE_NAME column in FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS
  --  and OTHER_RELEASE_INFO = null
  --
  -- If FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS.RELEASE_NAME contains imbedded spaces:
  --
  -- get_release() will return TRUE
  --  with RELEASE_NAME = FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS.RELEASE_NAME up to but
  --   not including the first imbedded space
  --  and OTHER_RELEASE_INFO = FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS.RELEASE_NAME
  --   starting with the first non-space character after the first
  --   imbedded space
  --
  -- On failure, get_release() returns FALSE. This will be a performance issue.
  --  Both RELEASE_NAME and OTHER_RELEASE_INFO will be set to 'Unknown'.
  --  This indicates that either:
  --  1) there are no rows in fnd_product_groups
  --     - this can be resolved by populating the row and it will
  --       be queried on the next call.
  --  2) there is more than one row in fnd_product_groups
  --     - delete all but the one correct row from fnd_product_groups and it
  --       will be queried on the next call. It's possible that the values
  --       returned by release_* and *_version routines are still correct if
  --       the first row in fnd_product_groups, ordered by product_group_id,
  --       if the currect row, but this will still be a performance problem.
```

Anybody face this problem before?!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see There is 3 possibilities:

1. Package **FND_RELEASE** compiled with invoker_rights_clause (`AUTHID CURRENT_USER`). And it use different source for user `apps` and for any other user.
2. function FND_RELEASE.get_release use `context` for access.
3. In your system used `private database` option. It able to rewrite queries and add condition to current user.(Variation of point 2 but implicitly)

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the Oracle e-Business Suite data model and packages.

In that software package, `FND_RELEASE` is declared as `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` (i.e., it uses invoker's rights).  You can see this in the 1st line of the package specification.

That means that the `FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS` table being looked at in this query...

```
select   release_name
from     fnd_product_groups
order by product_group_id;
```

... is *NOT* `APPS.FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS`.. it is the `FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS` table owned by the current user.

Since that user probably doesn't have an `FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS` table, `FND_RELEASE` is raising an `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` error when it tries to run that query.

That causes it to jump down to its `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler, which causes it to return false with the output parameters set to "Unknown".

One way around this issue is to create a custom wrapper for `FND_RELEASE` that uses definer's rights.  Like this:

```
create or replace package xxcust_fnd_release AUTHID DEFINER IS

  function get_release (release_name       out nocopy varchar2,
                        other_release_info out nocopy varchar2)
  return boolean;
end xxcust_fnd_release;


create or replace package body xxcust_fnd_release IS

  function get_release (release_name       out nocopy varchar2,
                        other_release_info out nocopy varchar2)
  return boolean IS
  BEGIN
    return fnd_release.get_release (release_name, other_release_info);
  END;
end xxcust_fnd_release;

grant execute on xxcust_fnd_release to <your_other_username>;
```

If you do that, and modify your script as follows, it will work:

```
declare
l_release_name         varchar2(30);
l_other_release_info   varchar2(2000);
   begin
     if not apps.XXCUST_FND_RELEASE.get_release (l_release_name, l_other_release_info) then
         null;
     end if;
     dbms_output.put_line(l_release_name);
   end;
```

#### ALTERNATE WORKAROUND

If you cannot or do not want to create a new wrapper package in the `APPS` schema, you can just create a synonym for `FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS` in your other user's schema.

E.g.,

```
create or replace synonym fnd_product_groups FOR apps.fnd_product_groups;
```

... do that in your other schema and your original script will work.

The downside to this alternative is that an Oracle patch may change the logic of `FND_RELEASE` to introduce other queries on other tables, causing this solution to break until you create whatever additional synonyms are required.